# A Linux Distribution for Nintendo DS Lite

Tags: linux, dsl

I want to use a linux OS on my Nintendo DS Lite. Tried to use the DSLinux, but it turned the device into white and non-responsive screens! Went on IRC channel and got the advice to learn C and solve the DSLinux problem!!!. So the question here is how I can peacefully get an operating system that I can run on my DS lite.

The following steps created the error:

- Got the file dslinux.tgz from http://www.dslinux.org/builds/.
- Unzipped the file and moved its folder into a SD card.
- Inserted the SD within R4SDHC adaptor card and turned on the DS.
- Went to its folder and chose the Linux Logo.

Then both screen went white.

Comment: We'd be more likely to help if you gave us a detailed account of what went wrong wen installing DSLinux. Simply trying another distro might or might not solve your issue, but isn't really the way to go, imho.

Comment: @rahmu thanks for the comment. Updated the question.